# Bootstrap: Using grid system getting three different sized items to line up

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get 3 different components to fit equally vertically, a left menu, a main image, and 2 side images.

This is the snippet I have so far:

http://www.bootply.com/xcIWtG0Z7w

2 things:

The bottom of the left component, middle image and bottom image of the side images should line up (as well as the respective tops), and 2, I will likely not know the sizes of the images ahead of time.

Is there anyway using the grid system to do this? I keep playing around with it and the only thing that works is arbitrary margins that break when I change the image sizes. I'm really not a front end person at all so I'm pretty sure I'm just not picturing it correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: This is the intended look (either one works for now):

[image]

[image]

Comment: do you want to stretch all the image to match the beiggest height image on page? or you want to keep the height fixed for all columns and leave white space at the bottom ??

Comment: Stretch. I'll draw a diagram to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bhavuksuthar/1abzyy5g/) of how to achieve this

Key element here is to `vertical-align` the content inside

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-height col-top">
    <div class="inside">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=9&amp;bg=654321&amp;txtclr=ffffff&amp;txt=LEFT%20MENU&amp;w=200&amp;h=550">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And here is `css` for it

```
.col-height {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
  height: 100%;
}
.col-top {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Now for the column with more than one image you can create multiple `div` inside or anything through which you can add padding between 2 image.

I hope you get the general idea of it

Comment: The demo doesn't fulfill the request, look at the right side box.